# Custom Thumbnails not working at all

Tags: php, wordpress, function, thumbnails

For some reason creating custom thumbnails won't work with WordPress, here's my code, any help would be greatly appreciated

**Functions.php**

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
        set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150 ); // default Post Thumbnail dimensions   
}

if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
    add_image_size( 'home-news', 560, 200, true );
}
```

**Page Template**

```
<div id="homeNewsThumbnail">
   <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
       the_post_thumbnail( 'home-news' ); 
   } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Crisis averted, apparently the theme caches everything and processes the crop sizes on upload, so all I needed to do was re-upload it and it produced the new crop size.

Comment: There are a [couple](http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) of [plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/) that regenerate thumbnails, no need to re-upload. Also, you can drop those `function_exists`, that's for backwards compatibility but heck who uses WP 2.x?